# Install BootCamp drivers Windows 10

Tags: bootcamp, windows, driver

I am looking for the exe files for BootCamp drivers for Windows 10. I installed Windows 10 on my Mac 4 months ago using the ISO and BootCamp assistant but then I reinstalled it directly on the partition which made the BootCamp drivers go away, and now some things (such as right click and two finger touchpad scrolling) don't work. I want to get the drivers without having to reinstall Windows (at the beginning Mac gives you the BootCamp installation files as an exe but I can't find them anywhere online.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**NEW SOLUTION**

Open Boot Camp Assistant, and click on "Action" in the menu bar.

[image]

Click on Download Windows Support Software.

**OLD SOLUTION**

You can download the drivers from Boot Camp Assistant.

First, uncheck "Create a Windows 7 or later install disk" and "Install Windows 7 or later version", leaving only "Download the latest Windows support software from Apple" option checked. It should look something like this:

[image: Boot Camp Assistant]

Make sure you have a USB drive connected, and click continue. You should see a screen like this:

[image: Boot Camp Storage Screen].

Select your drive and click on continue. It should download it to the connected USB drive.

Reboot into Windows, and install the support software from the USB.

Edit: I found [Brigadier](https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier), a software that fetches and installs the drivers for you on Windows. I'll take a look at it, when I have more time.

Comment: I don't see those options in BootCamp assistant :( http://imgur.com/a/64YAv (it's a large gif so give your browser some time to load it)

Comment: Also, just tried using Brigadier.exe and it downloaded it but it failed to install because the version of BootCamp it downloaded was designed for Windows 8.1: http://i.imgur.com/jWn0VAx.png

Comment: @kirill2485 What if you download it from Mac OS X? What is your Macbook model? I'll try downloading it for you.

Comment: its an early 2015 MacBook Pro Retina 13 inch

Comment: @kirill2485 Hi, I added a new solution. Can you try the new solution (top of my answer)

Comment: +1 for Brigadier. I needed that because my USB drives are all formatted with other formats.

Answer (score 1):

As of today Windows 10 1809 (October) will not work with bootcamp!
- windows will not find drivers
- windows will complain about selected drive
- etc etc

Use Windows 10 1803 (April) and bootcamp should work like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they do work... in powershell run the installer for the force switch. Apple puts a check in the installer for each model. The 1809 compatible installer must be downloaded from a Mac that was built after 1809 was released. Example Mac Mini 8,1. Create the boot camp installer from that hardware and you can run that installer on previous versions of Apple hardware in the CLI with the force install msi command..