# How do I reinstall Apple Software Update in Windows?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I uninstalled Apple Software Update in my Boot Camp Windows 7 install as it was crashing every launch, and a repair of Apple Software Update through Programs and Features didn't fix the problem.

However, re-running Boot Camp Tools' setup.exe (it gives me a choice to do a repair) does not reinstall the Apple Software Update it initially installed.

I suppose you could be in the same situation if you chose not to use Software Update when prompted during the Boot Camp Tools install.

How do I install the Apple Software Update associated with Boot Camp when Boot Camp is already installed?

Comment: can you explain this that in more detail please. I am having the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: @darshan I added a note about how to get the Windows support files. Was that what you needed to know?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, Software Update can be reinstalled by running `AppleSoftwareUpdate.msi` in the Boot Camp Windows support files under `Drivers` `Apple`

(To get the Boot Camp Windows support files, boot into Mac OS and use Boot Camp Assistant to save them to e.g. a USB drive that Windows will be able to read -- see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/247252/5231)

Answer (score 2):

I had the case of faulty/old installation of Apple Software Update, s.t. it would crash upon checking for update.

I managed to fix the issue as follows,

1. Get 7-zip
2. Go to [iTunes page](https://support.apple.com/downloads/itunes), get latest iTunes for your OS
3. Dissect iTunes with 7-zip, extract `AppleSoftwareUpdate.msi`
4. Run `AppleSoftwareUpdate.msi`, proceed with installation. It will automatically remove the old version and install newer files.