# How to install Windows 7 (and beyond) onto a mid-2010 Mac mini with Mac OS X Snow Leopard without Boot Camp or an optical (DVD) drive

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, startup, snow-leopard

This problem is very similar to [How to install Windows 10 into a 2011 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, an optical (DVD) drive or third party tools? - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/308743/369389), with the following additional limitations,

- **Mac OS X `v10.6.x` Snow Leopard** must not be upgraded.
- Because of old Mac OS X or otherwise, **Boot Camp Assistant does not function properly.**
- Because of old Mac OS X, old version of Boot Camp or Boot Camp Assistant, old/poorly supported hardware, old/poorly supported firmware, or otherwise, **your Mac crashes in [Windows GUI setup](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2006/05/vistab2/2/)** (or even in [EasyBCD BIOS Extender](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-boot-from-usb-drive-even-if-your-pc-doesnt-support-booting-from-usb/), "if your PC doesn’t support booting from USB.")
- Because of old Mac OS X or otherwise, **custom boot managers don't function properly** - with Windows failing to perform the boot into *any* GUI, before or after installation.

This Q&A answers how to install Windows 7 (**and beyond, e.g. Windows 10**) onto a mid-2010 Mac mini with Mac OS X Snow Leopard without Boot Camp or an optical (DVD) drive.

**This is a question with *specific constraints*** (pertinent to Mac OS X Snow Leopard compatibility). If these additional limitations don't apply to you, then you should likely follow: [How to install Windows 10 into a 2011 iMac without using the Boot Camp Assistant, an optical (DVD) drive or third party tools? - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/308743/369389)

I would desire to perform the installation ***without*** any of the following.

- <s>No third-party software</s> *(Third-party software, if any, should be minimal, and it should work with Mac OS X Snow Leopard)*
- No optical (DVD) drive
- No Boot Camp Assistant or it cannot be used properly.

Comment: The following questions may also offer useful answers: "[Boot camp install of Windows 7 issue, no bootable devices](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179486/boot-camp-install-of-windows-7-issue-no-bootable-devices)", "[Any solution to bootcamp windows 8.1 with macbook pro 15" 2010?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189335/any-solution-to-bootcamp-windows-8-1-with-macbook-pro-15-2010)" and "[No bootable device USB 2.0 MacBook Pro mid 2014](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014)".

Comment: TAbdiukov: I will be removing my answers to your question sometime early in April. I posted answers because what I found was difficult to post as comments. I never intended for the answers to persist at your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Installing Windows 7 (and beyond) onto a mid-2010 Mac mini with Mac OS X Snow Leopard without Boot Camp or an optical (DVD) drive.

In this guide, the following OS was used:

- Edition: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1
- Architecture: 32-bit

However, the guide itself is not limited to Windows 7 or 32-bit, and with modern "live image" options, the guide can be used to install (64-bit) Windows 8.1, 10 or beyond.

Furthermore, installing other operating systems, such as Linux should be possible with "Stage 4" approaches taken in this guide. More so, it should even be easier as you may skip Windows-specific steps. That said, Linux is out of scope of the guide.

The guide was tested on several *Macmini4,1* (Mid-2010), regardless of Intel CPU inside.

The procedure (guide) can be found below,

### Stage 1 - Meet prerequisites

*50% of work is meeting prerequisites! Meeting them can take a few hours.*

### Hardware

*ensure you have:*

- Target Mac machine with a spare volume for Windows.

  - Create a FAT (or exFAT, if [Mac OS X 10.6.5 or higher is used](https://www.macrumors.com/2010/11/11/mac-os-x-10-6-5-notes-exfat-support-airprint-flash-player-vulnerability-fixes/)) formatted volume labeled "BOOTCAMP". If this volume already exists, then erase the contents.

  > **Note:** At this point, the focus is on the partition's file system to be recognizable by Windows. The file system will be formatted to NTFS at a later stage.
- Spare Windows machine (regardless of installation OS)
- At least 2 USB sticks 16GB+. USB stick #1 is for **Mac OS X Recovery**, USB stick #2 is for **carrying over image files + driver and support files**, and maybe even USB stick #3 for 'in-case-ofs'.

### OS images

*files to obtain:*

#### 1/3: Installation OS image

*(such as a Windows 7 ISO)*

- Make sure to obtain an original (in Microsoft terms, "MSDN") ISO file for the correct architecture.
- After the image is obtained, it needs to be copied to your Mac.

#### 2/3: Mac OS X Recovery & Installation disk image

Make sure to obtain (roughly) the same release as of the Mac OS X already installed. You may use one of the following images,

- For the 10.6 release (2Z691-6558-A), you may wish to use [David Anderson's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/363745) to an unrelated question.
- [OS X 10.6.3 retail DMG file](https://archive.org/details/Mac.OS.X.10.6.3.Retail) - uploaded and tested by the original poster.
- [OS X 10.6.4 iso (.toast) file for the Macmini4,1](https://archive.org/download/691-6734-A2ZMac_mini._Mac_OS_X_Install_Disc._Mac_OS_v10.6.4._Disc_v1.0_DVD_DL).
- Finally, if your Mac is compatible, you may use [OS X 10.7 Lion DMG, officially offered by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102662)

Unlike all other OS images, Mac OS X Recovery & Installation disk image will not need to be copied to your Mac.

#### 3/3: Live image ISO

*A minimal WinPE environment*

"Live" means that it is possible to use a given OS without installation.

> **Note:** Live image ISO is only required for Windows installation process.

**After the image is obtained, it needs to be copied to your Mac.**

- **Update 26.12.2023**: Modern, official, and scalable solution to this step was found! - Sergei Strelec's WinPE (see below)

##### (Easy solution): Sergei Strelec's WinPE

[Sergei Strelec's WinPE (MajorGeeks)](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/sergei_strelecs_winpe.html)

At the time of writing, the current posted version is **`2023.06.25`**. [Screenshot of Sergei Strelec's WinPE successfully running within Parallels Desktop 5 on Mac OS X 10.6.3](https://imgur.com/a/fM7ANe7).

By using Sergei Strelec's WinPE, many problems are avoided, including:

- Having to obtain WinNTSetup, supplement with ADK files, and repack the utility of WinNTSetup.
- Potentially having to re-package installation image, due to Windows XP UDF issues.

The only downside is that the image is around 4.7GB, and temporarily, you need to use an NTFS-formatted storage device, or find another way to get the file onto your Mac.

Sergei Strelec's WinPE (in `WinPE 8 (x86)` environment) comes with last x86 host OS compatible, pre-packaged WinNTSetup v4.2.5. It also comes with 78Setup v2.4 (`Setup Windows 7-10 (x86-x64)`) utility, which was not researched in this answer. These 2 utilities **allow for installation of Windows 10 and beyond** on a `Mac mini 4,1`.

> **Note:** WinNTSetup v4.2.5 was previously successfully used to install Windows 10 using steps of this guide

###### Sergei Strelec's WinPE - Important Notes

*To keep the answer not too dependent on Sergei Strelec's WinPE, here are Important Notes*

- **Use at your own risk!**
- For compatibility reasons, Parallels Desktop's "target OS" has to be the highest available option, i.e. "Windows 7"
- For compatibility reasons, Sergei Strelec's WinPE may only be run in the mode of **`Boot WinPE 8 Sergei Strelec (x86) Native (Old PC)`**, [see screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/Nrp1cUd). Every other option causes Parallels Desktop 5 VM to crash.

  - Technically, Windows 8-based OS runs within virtualized environment that targets Windows 7, but no incompatibilities or issues were observed.
- Sergei Strelec's 8 WinPE runs on 1GB of VRAM with ~640MB of VRAM free.

##### (Your research): Other options

- Otherwise, due to constraints, it likely will be Windows XP/7/8 based, perhaps legal copy of MiniPE/BartPE. To keep guide neutral, you may benefit from finding an ISO at [system-repair](https://github.com/gamtiq/system-repair). Live image ISO will need to run WinNTSetup.

  - If WinNTSetup is not offered by live image, then ideally, the live image should produce a RAM Disk (usually, spanned using ImDisk software), allowing you to copy files to RAM. If it doesn't, there will be several extra steps. The RAM Disk [would look like this](https://www.megaleecher.net/uploads/Windows-RAMDisk-5.jpg).

### Software

*to obtain and install:*

#### On target Mac machine

[image: Parallels Desktop for Mac 5.x on Mac OS X 10.6 with Windows 7 installation]
*Note: Screenshot is for demonstration. Windows 7 will not be virtualized as in the screenshot.*

- Full version of Parallels Desktop for Mac 5-6 (or similar) for Mac OS X.

  - In this guide, **Parallels Desktop 5.0.9344.558741** was used.
  - **Parallels Desktop 5.0.9344.558741** requires activation with a **serial** number.
  - You need to install it on your target Mac machine.

#### On spare Windows machine

- [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html)
- (Required if Recovery disk is in DMG format): [TransMac](https://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm)

  - Trial version is OK
- ImgBurn, to generate ISO images from a folder (for Windows OS installations only). It is likely to come in handy for several ISO-specific steps.
- (Optional) VirtualBox or any other virtualization software. It may come in handy for 'WinNTSetup' steps below.

#### For 'live' image: WinNTSetup (only if WinNTSetup is not included; for Windows OS installations only).

**Trivia**: WinNTSetup is a finicky software that requires extra packages. Newer versions have better support for Windows 10/11, as well as extra options for customization. However, if live image already contains pre-configured WinNTSetup that 'gets job done', then it may be easier to use it and skip this step

**Note**: WinNTSetup [dropped Windows XP and 32-bit host OS support](https://www.maes.idv.tw/download/Files/Win10_Programs/WinNTSetup/5.2.6/WinNTSetup_v526/Changelog.txt) in version 4.5.0. As such, the last version compatible with any 32-bit 'live' environment is v4.2.5.

- Latest WinNTSetup versions are reported to require **ADK files**, which can normally be downloaded online, which may be an issue in 'live' environment. To ensure smooth experience, you may need to:

  - Download ADK files from Microsoft and place them in the WinNTSetup's `DISM` folder(s). For example, for version 4.2.5, DISM folders are located at,

    ```
    {{WinNTSetup}}\Tools\x64\DISM
    {{WinNTSetup}}\Tools\x86\DISM
    ```

    with respect to the CPU architecture.
  - Ensure that WinNTSetup works as expected in your live environment, for example, by using a virtualization software (e.g. VirtualBox), whereby you can attach your live image, attach WinNTSetup ISO image on another drive, and then ensure that WinNTSetup starts.
- Finally, create an ISO image with a portable copy of WinNTSetup using ImgBurn
- Optionally, you may re-pack your live environment to add your copy of WinNTSetup, as you will be able to attach WinNTSetup to your live environment.
- Once you are sure that WinNTSetup will work with live image, WinNTSetup ISO file needs to be copied to your Mac.

#### For Windows Installation:

##### 1/3: Boot Camp drivers

Thanks to a user's research using [this information](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/376921), it was determined that Macmini4,1 (Mac mini mid-2010) supports Windows 7 Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033 from [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016).

Make sure to install them, as otherwise, Windows will not be able to make use of hardware properly.

> **Note**: There is a community report that the combination of Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033 and 5.1.5722 can be used to install Windows 10. This information can be found at: [this post (steps 4-6)](https://reddit.com/r/mac/comments/6a3lpd/directives_to_install_windows_10_on_unsupported/) + [a comment (step 7)](https://reddit.com/r/mac/comments/6a3lpd/directives_to_install_windows_10_on_unsupported/dhj53lq/)

- [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630)
- [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5722](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1836)

##### 2/3: Updated "Apple Software Update" package.

As of 2023, Apple Software Update package supplied in `Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033` crashes. There are the following ways to address this problem:

- Use Apple Software update from [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5722](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1836)
   (or a newer Boot Camp Support Software version)
- Get latest iTunes that supports Windows 7 (which is [version 12.10.11.2 (April 23, 2021)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_iTunes#cite_note-211)), and extract Apple Software Update from it using [this method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/431554).

##### 3/3: Required Windows 7 SP1 updates

There are 2 possible options, and picking at least one option is **required**,

###### OP's minimal set of 2 updates

Minimal set of updates, required for Windows 7 to function.

- [KB4474419](https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb4474419) – SHA-2 signatures support (both for Windows Update and Apple Software Update)
- [KB3138612](https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb3138612) ([archive](https://archive.org/details/KB3138612)) – fix Windows Update "80072EFE" error.

###### David Anderson's "basically SP2"

Takes care of 112 update packages, installable in order specified,

- KB3020369
- KB3125574
- KB4474419 *(from above)*
- KB4490628
- KB5011649

#### Save time!

- [USB stick #1] *(macOS Recovery)*: On your spare Windows machine, use TransMac (for .DMG and .toast) or any ImgBurn (for .toast) to start burning Mac OS X Recovery image to USB #1.
- [USB stick #2] *(ISO, Drivers and support)*: Format USB #2 to use FAT (or exFAT, if [Mac OS X 10.6.5 or higher is used](https://www.macrumors.com/2010/11/11/mac-os-x-10-6-5-notes-exfat-support-airprint-flash-player-vulnerability-fixes/) file system, and copy ISO/DMG images, plus everything that will be required for the future Windows 7 installation (Boot Camp drivers, Updated "Apple Software Update" package, Required Windows 7 SP1 updates) to USB #2.

> **Note:** Use USB #2 to transfer over big .ISO files. So, USB #2 is your 'cargo' drive.

### Stage 2 - Create virtual environment

#### Create New Windows Installation using Parallels Desktop 5 Wizard

1. Launch **Parallels Desktop for Mac**
2. Click on **New Windows Installation**
   [image: Splash]
3. In the **Operating System Detection** window, attach your **live image**,
   [image: Attach DVD 1]
4. Regardless of Parallels Desktop detection or lack thereof, ensure that that "Detected Operating System" closely corresponds to your **live image OS** (not installation OS). In my case, my live image OS is based on Windows XP, so I selected corresponding option,
   [image: Could not detect OS]

   > **Note:** For WinPE 8 Sergei Strelec (x86) or any other Windows 8 based live environments, pick "Windows 7", being the closest available option in Parallels Desktop 5 for Mac.
5. In the **Virtual Machine Type** window, select **Custom** and click **Continue**,
   [image: Virtual Machine Type - Custom]
6. In the **CPU and Memory Options** window, I left everything as-is and clicked **Continue**,
   [image: CPU and Memory Options]
7. In the **Hard Disk Options** window, select **Boot Camp Partition**. Is this options is generally risky, you may receive some warnings,
   [image: Hard Disk Opt: Boot Camp Partition]
8. In the **Boot Camp Disk** window, select **disk0** (i.e. the Mac's internal disk),
   [image: Boot Camp Disk - Always disk0]
9. In the **Networking Type** window, it is advised (for security reasons) to select **No Networking**,
   [image: Networking Type - No Networking]
10. In the **Optimization Options** window, the default option of: "optimizations **for a Virtual Machine**" makes better sense (as it will use many resources for itself in the process), leave everything as-is and click **Continue** to proceed,
    [image: Optimize for: VM]
11. In the **Name and Location** window, you may opt for a fancy VM name (such as `Winstall`) and click **Create**,
    [image: Fancy Winstall]
12. You should be greeted by a window like this,
    [image: Winstall is ready]
    Do not click on the VM just yet.

#### Configure VM

- **Important Note:** After the virtual machine is created. More configuring will be required, so **do not launch VM just yet**. If you launched your VM, simply stop it for now, by selecting,

  ```
  Top menu bar -> Virtual Machine -> Stop
  ```

1. Now proceed to the virtual machine configuration, by selecting,

   ```
   Top menu bar -> Virtual Machine -> Configure
   ```
2. Within opened window, select furthest to the right tab of **Hardware**,
   [image: Rightmost "Hardware" Tab]
3. Select **CD/DVD 1**, ensure it is **Connected**, and direct **Source** to **live image ISO** *(2<sup>nd</sup> time)*,
   [image: CD/DVD 1: my_live_image.iso]
4. Underneath "devices" section, find and click on the **<kbd>+</kbd> (Add)** button, and then select **CD/DVD**,
   [image: Cut plus option screen]
5. You have now added a second CD/DVD drive. Select **CD/DVD 2**, ensure it is **Connected**, and direct **Source** to **installation image ISO**,
   [image: CD/DVD 2: en_windows_7_]
6. Select **Floppy Disk**. Pre-empt Parallels Desktop complaints: ensure it is **not** **Connected**, by unticking Connected checkbox,
   [image: Floppy Disk - Not Connected]
7. Finally, select **Boot Order**. Ensure that **CD/DVD is above** any of the Hard Disks,
   [image: Boot Order: CD/DVD above HDDs]
   *Optionally*, you may enable "Select boot device on startup", though you won't need it.

> **Note:** If you *absolutely* know that WinNTSetup is external to the live image, and RAM Disk (usually, spanned using ImDisk software) is not offered by your live image, then you may repeat the steps 4-5 to attach a third CD/DVD drive, that will use that external WinNTSetup ISO.

### Stage 3 - 'Install' Windows in VM

#### Getting started in live environment

1. Launch the VM.

- **Important Note:** In stage 3, including now, you will encounter a message like this a few times,
  [image: Security Error Brief]
  Don't tick anything, and just click "OK". You want to monitor these security messages in the process.

2. Ensure installation ISO is attached to any CD/DVD **except** CD/DVD 1. Its files will be used as WinNTSetup input.

   > **Note:** Some older live images (e.g. Windows XP SP2 based) struggle with Windows 7 DVD UDF (ISO 9660 noncompliant) file system, and incorrectly detect it as CDFS. If this happens, then the Windows 7 installation files will have to be provided another way. For example, this can be done by: sourcing Windows 7 files to ImgBurn, and creating a data-only, ISO 9660 compliant DVD image with these files, without bootable functionality. ImgBurn will complain a few times, but since the files will only be used as raw input for WinNTSetup, bootability is not an important factor.
3. Ensure WinNTSetup is available to the live image.

   - If WinNTSetup is external, and is not packed into the live image, then copy WinNTSetup folder onto the RAM Disk.

     - If RAM Disk, is not offered by a live image (as it is, usually, spanned using ImDisk software), then you will need to either repack your live image with ImgBurn to include WinNTSetup OR use a third CD/DVD drive in the next step.
   - If WinNTSetup is available within the live image, then you can simply run it.

#### Formatting the partition

WinNTSetup is not designed to format the drive, so you are better off formatting it yourself.

Yes, Windows will run on FAT/FAT32 file system. However, Windows will run more stable on NTFS, as NTFS has capabilities for better error-detection and error-correction, as well as journaling.

> **Note:** Windows XP [does not support formatting from within `diskpart`](https://superuser.com/a/100747)

You may use any tool or app for format process. However, to keep it simple, as well as to minimize risk of formatting macOS partition, it is recommended to simply use basic Windows inbuilt format utility.

- To use it, to go "My Computer", right-click on the partition to which Windows will be installed, and select "Format".

Ensure to **format to NTFS.**

Parallels Desktop for Mac will complain of an [error writing boot loader](https://i.imgur.com/xzXkMgz.png) (MBR). This is OK and expected.

#### Marking partition as "active"

##### Problem

If you were to use WinNTSetup now and specify Bootdrive,
[image: WinNTSetup 2-1 Inactive]

Then you may notice that **BOOT FLAG** indicator is inactive (red).

It should otherwise be fixed by WinNTSetup. However, some builds of WinNTSetup do not appear to perform this change for the user. Luckily, the solution is simple and easy.

##### Solution - `diskpart`

1. Run the following command-line tool,

   ```
   diskpart
   ```
2. `diskpart` utility is interactive. Enter the command below to list volumes.

   ```
   list volume
   ```
3. Select volume with future Windows installation on it. Replace `#` with the volume number for this volume,

   ```
   select volume #
   ```
4. Set volume as active

   ```
   active
   ```

   Parallels Desktop for Mac will complain of an [error writing boot loader](https://i.imgur.com/xzXkMgz.png) (MBR). This is OK and expected.
5. Exit `diskpart`

   ```
   exit
   ```

In the "WinNTSetup" steps below, `BOOT PART` check should now be green (passed).

#### WinNTSetup

1. Start WinNTSetup.
2. Ensure that **`BOOT PART`** indicator is active (green). If not, mark partition as "active" as described above.
3. Begin configuring installation:

   - Select a top panel corresponding to your installation Windows release (e.g. Windows 7, not Windows 2000)
   - Select location to `INSTALL.WIM` file, within installation image. It is typically a large (2GB+) file within installation DVD. For example, if installation image is mounted to disk `D:\`, then the .WIM file in question may probably be found in,

     ```
     D:\Sources\Install.wim
     ```
   - For **Boot Drive** and **Installation Drive** locations, select partition (i.e. a drive letter) to which Windows will be installed.
   - In options below: Select desired Windows **Edition**
   - In options below: Check **drive letter preassignment**.
   - In options below: Select **Mount Installation Drive** to be **`C:`** (otherwise, Windows may later be found on `D:`)

   The resulting configuration should look like this,
   [image: Early WinNTSetup v2]
4. Click on "Setup". You will proceed to the next window.
5. In the **Ready?** window, observe both "Bootdrive" and "Installationdrive" being configured properly. Most importantly, ensure that for **Bootsector** option, **Use bootsect.exe to update the boot code** (default option) is selected,
   [image: WinNTSetup - Ready?]
6. Finally, click "OK" and observe WinNTSetup begin its process.
7. Toward completion of WinNTSetup operation, as WinNTSetup is **Updating boot code**, Parallels Desktop for Mac will complain of an [error writing boot loader](https://i.imgur.com/xzXkMgz.png) (MBR). This is OK and expected,
   [image: WinNTSetup - boot code]

   > **Note**: WinNTSetup runs `bootsect.exe` at this point.
8. Wait a bit more and observe WinNTSetup completing its process and informing that "Setup is done",
   [image: WinNTSetup - Finish]
9. Once WinNTSetup is finished, close the program and perform a sanity check. Open WinNTSetup again and (as though you wanted to use it again) briefly go through configuration again. Once **Bootdrive location** is configured, ensure that all checkmarks are ticked and green,
   [image: WinNTSetup - all green]

The installation is largely complete. However, as can be inferred by [errors writing boot loader](https://i.imgur.com/xzXkMgz.png), Mac will not boot to the second OS. There is no rapid way to rectify this, so you'll need to use the Mac OS recovery disk.

### Stage 4 - Overwrite MBR

#### In Mac OS X production

Even though we previously opted to use "Boot Camp Partition", Parallels Desktop for Mac will create an `.hdd` folder with drive's intended MBR. This .hdd folder will be present once stage 3 is complete.

1. Obtain the VM .hdd folder in

```
/Users/{{UserName}}/Documents/Parallels/{{VM name}}/
```

The resource will be several kilobytes.

2. Copy this folder elsewhere (for example, to "Downloads" folder) and rename it to `vm.hdd`
3. Backup this `vm.hdd` to USB #2.

#### Create Mac OS X recovery disk

- Use TransMac (for .DMG and .toast) or any ImgBurn (for .toast) burn Mac OS X Recovery image to USB stick #1, if you haven't yet (see **Save time!**). This will take about half an hour.

#### In Mac OS X Recovery mode

1. Attach USB stick #1 with Mac OS X recovery disk and USB stick #2 with `vm.hdd` to the Mac. Turn off/restart the Mac.
2. Boot your Mac from recovery disk: hold <kbd>Option</kbd> key when booting and select "Mac OS X Install DVD".
3. Open Disk Utility and take note of your installation drive ID and the volume that contains `vm.hdd`. **Be prudent and write it down!** For example, it may be that: `/dev/disk0` is your Windows installation drive and `/Volumes/USB2/` is your USB #2 **with `vm.hdd`** inside.
4. While still in disk utility, unmount every partition of the installation drive, so that the drive is not busy.
5. Open Terminal

   - 1/4: Sanity check: confirm your {{installation_drive}} by running,

     ```
     diskutil list
     ```
   - 2/4: Ensure USB #2's `vm.hdd` (and `PhysicalMbr.hds` inside of it) can be accessed by Mac OS X Recovery disk, by running the following commands,

     ```
     ls /Volumes/{{USB2}}
     ls /Volumes/{{USB2}}/vm.hdd
     cat /Volumes/{{USB2}}/vm.hdd/PhysicalMbr.hds
     ```

     *`ls` returns directory listing, `cat` prints file contents*
   - 3/4: Backup original MBR,

     ```
     dd if=/dev/{{installation_drive}} of=/Volumes/{{USB2}}/backupMBR bs=512 count=1
     ```
   - 4/4: Overwrite the installation boot sector,

     ```
     dd if=/Volumes/{{USB2}}/vm.hdd/PhysicalMbr.hds of=/dev/{{installation_drive}} bs=512 count=1
     ```
   - (Optional): Sanity-check. Run something like,

     ```
     head -n 5 /dev/{{installation_drive}}
     ```

     to confirm that the MBR was overwritten. Prior to `EFI`, You should see some Google-able strings used by Windows in the event of boot errors.

> **Note:** Even if MBR was overwritten successfully and as required, you will not be able to use `Startup Disk` utility to immediately boot straight to Windows. The reason for this likely has to do with Mac boot loader code having to detect Windows installation first.

6. Sanity check. Reboot to Mac OS X first, to ensure it still boots. If not, you may roll back (revert) changes by using the `backupMBR` file. Additionally, ensure that Mac OS X now detects another boot volume.
7. Reboot again, holding <kbd>Option</kbd> key. Next, hold down the <kbd>Control</kbd> key while choosing the circular arrow below the "Windows" label.

> **Note:** The "circular arrow" while holding <kbd>Control</kbd> key tells Mac boot code to load to Windows by default, reducing headache with subsequent reboots.

### Stage 5 - Prepare Windows

> **Note:** The steps in this section were partially derived from [David Anderson's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308812) to an unrelated question.

#### Getting started with SysPrep Phase

1. Boot into Windows. You should be greeted by "Set up Windows" window like this,
   [image: Set up Windows]
2. Next, press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> keys to restart Windows in Audit mode. If you are using a wireless keyboard, then you may have to utilize the On-Screen Keyboard. See `Ease of access` on the lower left of the screen.
3. (Suggestion) At this point, prohibiting your Mac access to the internet is generally a good idea, not so much because of telemetry, but because necessary software and updates are not yet installed.
4. Turn off Windows Update service temporarily.

   - Using Start menu, launch `services.msc`.
   - Locate `Windows Update`.
   - Change "Startup type" to "Manual".
   - If the service is running, stop it using "Stop" button.
   - Close the "Services" window.
5. If you prohibited your Mac access to the internet in an earlier step, you will now want to allow access. In other words, plug in the ethernet cable or connect by Wi-Fi.
6. *If you haven't yet in **Save time!** section*, then obtain **drivers and support files** and save them on USB #2. Now, transfer them over to the Windows installation: Attach USB #2 with **drivers and support files** on it, and install them in the following order,

#### Boot Camp Drivers

Recall that for Windows 7, you need to use Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033. Install these drivers using the aforementioned package.

> **Note:** Wi-Fi connection to the internet may not work the *very first* time Wi-Fi connectivity is attempted, even with correct credentials. If such problem occurs, simply disconnect from the Wi-Fi hotspot and connect back.

#### Required Windows Updates

**Without required Windows Updates, further steps are not possible.** Recall that there are 2 possible options, of which a least 1 must be picked,

- OP's minimal set of 2 updates
- David Anderson's "basically SP2"

Install either or both to proceed.

#### Update "Apple Software Update"

Recall that, as of 2023, you may extract updated `Apple Software Update` from either Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5722 or extract it from iTunes.

Once it is obtained (ideally, on your spare Windows machine), install updated `Apple Software Update` on Windows 7 installation. The package will perform an update without any additional troubles.

#### Apple Software Update

1. Start Apple Software Update.
2. When executed the first time, even after an update above, "Apple Software Update" will ask to update "Apple Software Update" itself. Update Apple Software Update first, as the version that comes with Apple Software Update is outdated (~2020). You should uncheck all other updates and just update "Apple Software Update". Otherwise, you may get an error message. In my case, there were two updates of the "Apple Software Update" to download and install.
3. Update everything else, until there is nothing to update.

For steps 2-3, feel free to reboot as many times as necessary.

#### (Optional) Further update Windows via Windows Update

1. Open Control Panel -> Windows Update. On the side panel, click on "Change Settings". Select a desired update plan. For example, `Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them`. Click "OK".
2. If Windows Update hasn't done so automatically, initiate the process by clicking on "Check for updates" on the side panel.
3. Download and install Windows updates, including perhaps any optional updates. You may want to skip this step for now. However, skipping this step may result in some hardware drivers not being updated.

#### `Sysprep` utility

1. From the Windows Start menu, restart the Mac. Once restarted, if the "System Preparation Tool" window is not displayed, run `C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe`. Then select "Shutdown" under the "Shutdown options",
   [image: Sysprep]
2. Next, select "OK" to shutdown the Mac. **At this point, you have completed the Windows installation process.**

Answer (score 0):

TAbdiukov provided both the question and an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740). My answer is modeled after TAbdiukov's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740) with the following major differences:

- I used VirtualBox instead of Parallels.
- The ***ONLY*** third party software used is VirtualBox.
- VirtualBox is a free product. Parallels no longer offers free trials for versions compatible with Snow Leopard.
- Unlike Parallels, VirtualBox does not require an activation key. Parallels no longer sells activation keys for versions compatible with Snow Leopard.

### My Test Environment

I do not have a 2010 Mac mini. I do not have a version of Parallels old enough to be used for testing. I substituted the following.

- A 2007 iMac with 4 GB of memory. Snow Leopard (64 bit) 10.6.8 was the host when VirtualBox 4.3.40 was used. The VirtualBox guests were 32 bit Windows 7 installers.
- A 2013 iMac with 16 GB of memory. Catalina 10.15.7 was the host when Fusion Player 12.1.2 was used. The Fusion Player guests were Lion 10.7.5 and 32 bit Windows 7. Lion was used, because I did not have a Snow Leopard that would run in Fusion Player. Lion was the host when VirtualBox 4.3.40 was used. The VirtualBox guests were 32 bit Windows 7 installers. This nested use of virtual machines allowed me to virtualize both the host and guest.

### My Version of TAbdiukov's Answer.

TAbdiukov's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740) provides an example where Parallels Desktop 5 for Mac is used to install a 32 bit Windows 7. I do not have the required activation key to use this version of Parallels. Instead, I substituted VirtualBox 4.3.40, which allowed for the installation of Windows without having to use Sergei Strelec's WinPE or WinNTSetup. However, if one wished, installing using Sergei Strelec's WinPE or just WinNTSetup is possible with the use of VirtualBox.

Note that a virtual machine only is used to help install Windows. Once Windows is installed, the virtual machine is not needed and can be removed.

> Note: [According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/100503), Windows 7 is supposed to include Service Pack 1 (SP1). Although, some users here at Ask Different have reported success by using Windows 7 without SP1. This answer assumes SP1 is included.

What is needed (beyond the Mac with Snow Leopard installed):

- A computer that can download and copy files to a flash drive.
- 32 bit Windows 7 ISO file.
- 16 GB or larger flash drive.
- VirtualBox 4.3.40 which is compatible with at least 32/64 bit Windows XP through 32/64 bit Windows 10 guests. VirtualBox is free software where all current and previous releases are available for download.
- All other files needed are free and can be downloaded from the internet. This answer requires no third party tools other than VirtualBox.
- While you may not need a product key to install Windows 7, you probably will need a product key at some point after the software is installed in order to activate Windows 7.

What is **not** required:

- DVDs
- Optical drives

Below are the steps to follow.

1. **Make a partition for Windows 7.**

   Use the Disk Utility application or `diskutil` command to create a partition at the end of the drive where Windows will be installed. Format the partition as MS-DOS, MS-DOS (FAT), or ExFAT with the `BOOTCAMP` volume name. Later, the format will be changed to NTFS.

   The table below shows the expected partitions to appear in the output from the `diskutil list` command for `disk0`. If you have a different partition arrangement from the those shown, then you will have to make the appropriate adjustments to this answer.

   **Table: Expected `disk0` Partitions**

   | # | Type | Format | Identifier | Description |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | `EFI` | MS-DOS (FAT32) | `disk0s1` | Hidden EFI |
   | 2 | `Apple_HFS` | Mac OS Extended (Journeled) | `disk0s2` | Contains Mac OS X Snow Leopard |
   | 3 | `Microsoft Basic Data` | MS-DOS (FAT32) or ExFAT | `disk0s3` | Will Contain Windows 7 |
2. **FAT32 or ExFAT format an 8 GB or larger flash drive.**

   If the Disk Utility application is used to erase the flash drive, then refer to the table below. If the ExFAT format is being used, then the Mac, where Windows is to be installed, needs Snow Leopard version Mac OS X 10.6.5 or later installed.

   **Table: Choices for Disk Utility Flash Drive Erase**

   | Label | Snow Leopard Mac OS X 10.6 or later | Snow Leopard Mac OS X 10.6.5 or later |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | Name | WINSTALL | WINSTALL |
   | Format | MS-DOS (FAT) | ExFAT |
   | Scheme | Master Boot Record | Master Boot Record |
3. **Copy files to the flash drive.**

   Here the assumption is made that a computer with a new enough operating system is being used to download the necessary files.

   Use the following sources.

   - Copy a 32 bit Windows 7 ISO file to the root folder on the `WINSTALL` volume. This volume is on the flash drive. Here, I used the file `GSP1RMCPRXFRER_EN_DVD.ISO`, which is a 32 bit Windows 7 SP1 installer ISO file downloaded from [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/win-7-pro-32-64-iso). FYI, I did not verify the authenticity of this file.
   - Create a folder named `BootCamp` on the root folder of the flash drive. Copy the Windows Support Software for 32 bit Windows 7 to this `BootCamp` folder. According to the Apple website [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016), the version of the Windows Support Software for installing 32 bit Windows 7 on your Mac is [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630).
   - Download the [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5722](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1836), then copy the file `AppleSoftwareUpdate.msi` in the `BootCamp\Drivers\Apple` folder of this download to the root folder on the `WINSTALL` volume. Next, copy the file AutoUnattend.xml in the root folder of this download to the root folder on the WINSTALL volume.
   - Download VirtualBox 4.3.40 for OS X hosts file `VirtualBox-4.3.40-110317-OSX.dmg` from the [Download VirtualBox (Old Builds): VirtualBox 4.3](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3) website. Copy this file to the root folder on the `WINSTALL` volume. VirtualBox 4.3.40 is documented to be compatible with at least 32/64 bit Windows XP through 32/64 bit Windows 10 guests.
   - Download the ZIP file containing the `mywindows` script from my [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/maclinks/71ff296315852afd2c0e9c67aece22c9). From the download, extract a copy of the `mywindows` script to the root folder on the `WINSTALL` volume.
   - Goto the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx) and copy the files given in the following table to the root folder on the `WINSTALL` volume. Each file can be found by searching for the corresponding hotfix.

   **Table: Hotfixes Available from Microsoft Update Catalog**

   | Hotfix | Description | File Name |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | KB3020369 | April 2015 servicing stack update for x86 Windows 7 | `windows6.1-kb3020369-x86_82e168117c23f7c479a97ee96c82af788d07452e.msu` |
   | KB3125574 | Convenience rollup update for x86 Windows 7 SP1 | `windows6.1-kb3125574-v4-x86_ba1ff5537312561795cc04db0b02fbb0a74b2cbd.msu` |
   | KB4474419 | SHA-2 code signing support update for x86 Windows 7: September 23, 2019 | `windows6.1-kb4474419-v3-x86_0f687d50402790f340087c576886501b3223bec6.msu` |
   | KB4490628 | Servicing stack update for x86 Windows 7 SP1: March 12, 2019 | `windows6.1-kb4490628-x86_3cdb3df55b9cd7ef7fcb24fc4e237ea287ad0992.msu` |
   | KB5011649 | Servicing stack update for x86 Windows 7 SP1: March 8, 2022 | `windows6.1-kb5011649-x86_fce83439d6e9707053b0db1a3eb21f5caedd2e7b.msu` |

   When finished, the USB flash drive should appear as follows.

   [image: files]
4. **Install VirtualBox and build a virtual machine.**

   Move the flash drive to the Mac where Windows is to be installed. Open a Terminal application window and enter the following command. This will remove any extended attributes on the flash drive that might interfere with the installation of Windows.

   > Note: The outputs from the `mywindows` script are given in the appendix of this answer.

   ```
   /bin/bash /Volumes/WINSTALL/mywindows clean
   ```

   Using the file `VirtualBox-4.3.40-110317-OSX.dmg` in the root folder on the `WINSTALL` volume, install VirtualBox 4.3.40. This volume resides on the USB flash drive.

   Execute the following commands to build the virtual machine named `MyWindows`. The command below changes the current directory to the root folder of the `WINSTALL` volume on the flash drive.

   ```
   cd /Volumes/WINSTALL
   ```

   The next command hybrid partitions internal drive where Windows is to be installed. This is done to ensure the partition where Windows is to be installed is the active partition and the partition type is set to `07`.

   ```
   ./mywindows hybrid
   ```

   The next command creates a `~/VirtualBox\ VMs/support.iso` ISO file containing any additional files needed that do not exist in the `GSP1RMCPRXFRER_EN_DVD.ISO` ISO file. In this case, the only file needed is `AutoUnattend.xml` in the `/Volumes/WINSTALL` folder. A copy of this file will be placed in the `support.iso` ISO file under the name `MyAutoUnattend.xml`. Renaming is necessary to prevent the Windows installer from automatically reading this file.

   ```
   ./mywindows iso
   ```

   The next command creates the virtual machine. The memory is set to 512 MB and the number of processors is set to 1. The memory will be sufficient enough to run the Windows 7 installer. Two virtual optical drives are added which contain virtual DVDs created from the `GSP1RMCPRXFRER_EN_DVD.ISO` and `support.iso` files. The location where Windows will be installed is the `disk0s3` partition on the physical internal drive.

   ```
   ./mywindows create -i Windows7 -m 512 GSP1RMCPRXFRER_EN_DVD.ISO
   ```
5. **Install a BIOS bootable PE in the `BOOTCAMP` volume.**

   Enter the command below to start the virtual machine. If the message `Press any key to boot from CD or DVD.` appears, press the space bar.

   ```
   ./mywindows start
   ```

   > Note: At this point, the Mac is running from the in-memory PE, which was read from `boot.wim` file after booting from the `GSP1RMCPRXFRER_EN_DVD` volume on one of the virtual optical drives.

   When a display similar to the one shown below appears, make any necessary selections, then press the "Next" button.

   [image: Initial display]

   When a display similar to the one shown below appears, press the key combination <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open a Command Prompt window.

   [image: Second display]

   Enter the following command to get the different letters assigned to the `BOOTCAMP` and `support` volumes. The letters should be C: and E:, respectively. If not, then make the appropriate substitutions when entering commands.

   ```
   wmic logicaldisk get description,name,volumename
   ```

   Enter the following command to NTFS format drive C:.

   ```
   format c: /v:BOOTCAMP /q
   ```

   Enter the next command to start installing Windows 7.

   ```
   setup /noreboot /unattend:e:\myautounattend.xml
   ```

   Proceed with the installation of Windows to the `BOOTCAMP` volume, until a display similar to the one shown below appears. Highlight the desired operating system, then select the "Next" button.

   [image: Choose OS]

   Proceed with the installation of Windows to the `BOOTCAMP` volume. When the Command Prompt windows to reappears, enter the following command to close the window.

   ```
   exit
   ```

   Next, select "Repair your computer". When a display similar to the one shown below appears, press the "Next >" button.

   [image: System Recovery Options]

   When a display similar to the one shown below appears, press the "Shut Down" button.

   [image: Shut Down]
6. **Update the internal drive MBR.**

   Enter the command below to update the internal drive MBR boot code. This includes the bytes at offsets 0x000 through 0x1BD of the MBR.

   ```
   ./mywindows update
   ```

   At this point, you are done with the virtual machine.
7. **Finish Installing Windows 7.**

   From the Startup Disk pane of the System Preferences application, select "Windows on BOOTCAMP", as shown below.

   [image]

   Next, restart the Mac. Proceed with the Windows installation until a display similar to the one shown below appears.

   > Note: At this point, use of an external wired mouse and/or keyboard may be temporarily required. The on–screen keyboard can also be temporarily substituted for an actual keyboard. To access the on–screen keyboard, select the "Ease of access" button shown in the lower left of the window in the image below.

   [image: on-screen keyboard]

   > Note: With the installation of Windows versions newer than Windows 7, I might suggest temporarily prohibiting your Mac access to the internet, then restarting in Audit mode. **However, with Windows 7 this is unnecessary, since the software will allow you to temporarily disable automatic updates.**

   Proceed with the installation. When a display similar to the one shown below appears, select "Ask me later". This will temporarily disable automatic updates.

   [image: Auto update]
8. **Install additional software.**

   Once the setup of Windows 7 is complete, execute the Boot Camp Installer Version 4.0 (Build 4033) by opening the `setup` application in the `BootCamp` folder on the `WINSTALL` volume. This volume resides on the USB flash drive.

   > Note: If you are adapting these instructions to install a 64 bit Windows 7 (or newer), then the `setup` application should open automatically.

   The Boot Camp Installer will install additional drivers for your Mac's hardware. If a display similar to the one shown below appears, uncheck "Apple Software Update for Windows", then select the button "Install".

   [image: Install Apple Software Update]

   After the Boot Camp Installer has completed and the Mac has restarted, install the hotfixes in the root folder on the `WINSTALL` volume. This volume resides on the USB flash drive. These hotfixes are needed to get Apple Software Update and Windows Update to work. Install the hotfixes in the following order.

   ```
   windows6.1-kb3020369-x86_82e168117c23f7c479a97ee96c82af788d07452e.msu
   windows6.1-kb3125574-v4-x86_ba1ff5537312561795cc04db0b02fbb0a74b2cbd.msu
   windows6.1-kb4474419-v3-x86_0f687d50402790f340087c576886501b3223bec6.msu
   windows6.1-kb4490628-x86_3cdb3df55b9cd7ef7fcb24fc4e237ea287ad0992.msu
   windows6.1-kb5011649-x86_fce83439d6e9707053b0db1a3eb21f5caedd2e7b.msu
   ```

   Install Apple Software Update by opening the `AppleSoftwareUpdate` Windows installer package in the root folder on the `WINSTALL` volume. This volume resides on the USB flash drive. Afterwards, use the Apple Software Update application to get any new software available from Apple. Note the following:

   - You should install any updates to Apple Software Update first before installing other updates available from Apple.
   - You may need to download only, then manually install downloads.
   - You may need to copy any downloads before Apple Software Update deletes the downloads.
   - iTunes appears to be incompatible, so you may want to skip any iTunes updates.

   When finished, go to the Windows Update screen shown below and choose your settings, then download and install all currently available updates shown.

   > Note: In previous versions of this answer, instructions were given to install Microsoft Edge. However, Microsoft Edge should now be installed automatically, if all available updates are installed. After Microsoft Edge is installed, you may wish to visit the Control Panel to set Microsoft Edge as default. In other words, use Microsoft Edge to open all file types and protocols it can open by default.

   [image]

---

### Clean Up

- **How to Remove the Virtual Machine**

  From Mac OS X, enter the command given below in a Terminal application window.

  ```
  /Volumes/WINSTALL/mywindows remove
  ```
- **Uninstalling VirtualBox**

  Since VirtualBox takes very little space, I would recommend not removing the application. However, if you wish to uninstall, then open the `VirtualBox-4.3.40-110317-OSX.dmg` file `VirtualBox-4.3.40-110317-OSX.dmg` in the root folder on the `WINSTALL` volume. This volume resides on the USB flash drive. Open the `VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool` file and follow the instructions to uninstall VirtualBox.

### Other Possible Answers

- If one wanted to install Windows 10 on a 2010 Mac mini, then the following might work. With Snow Leopard installed, create a new partition and install High Sierra for a Snow Leopard/High Sierra dual boot arrangement. This would update the firmware. Erase High Sierra. The firmware update would remain. There is a very good chance that one could use [a different answer of mine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant/308812#308812) (with perhaps some minor changes) to install Windows 10.
- If [my other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308743/how-to-install-windows-10-into-a-2011-imac-without-using-the-boot-camp-assistant/308812#308812) worked for Windows 10, then a Windows 10 installer could be used to install Windows 7. This would mean the use of Parallels, VirtualBox or any other VM would be unnecessary. If the Mac mini is a used machine, then the High Sierra firmware update may have already been installed. One might want to copy the files from a mounted Windows 10 ISO to a ExFAT formatted flash drive and see if the 2010 Mac mini can EFI boot from this flash drive.

### Appendix

The output given is typical. Your output might vary. Version 2.1.4 of `mywindows` was used to create the output.

Output from the `/bin/bash /Volumes/WINSTALL/mywindows clean` command.

```
$ # Enter the commands below to remove ._* files after merging the ._* files
$ # with corresponding native files.
$ dot_clean -f /Volumes/WINSTALL
$ find /Volumes/WINSTALL -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \! -name .Spotlight-V100 \! -name .TemporaryItems \! -name .Trashes -exec dot_clean {} +

***************
*** SUCCESS ***
***************
```

Output from the `./mywindows hybrid` command.

```
mywindows hybrid: Since this verb requires elevated privileges, sudo is being used to execute the command as root.
Password:
mywindows hybrid: Using implicit device: BOOTCAMP
mywindows hybrid: gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
$ # Enter the commands below to hybrid partition the physical drive.
$ unset Input
$ declare "Input="
$ Input+="edit 1;ee;n;1;409639;"
$ Input+="edit 2;af;n;409640;976426672;"
$ Input+="edit 3;07;n;977098752;976424960;"
$ Input+="edit 4;0;"
$ Input+="flag 3;quit;y"
$ Input="${Input//;/$'\n'}"
$ sudo fdisk -ef /dev/zero /dev/disk0 <<<"$Input" >/dev/null
$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 121601/255/63 [1953525168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  976426672] HFS+        
*3: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 977098752 -  976424960] HPFS/QNX/AUX
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      

***************
*** SUCCESS ***
***************
```

Output from the `./mywindows iso` command.

```
$ # Enter the commands below to create the ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/support.iso file.
$ mkdir -p ~/VirtualBox\ VMs
$ pushd ~/VirtualBox\ VMs
~/VirtualBox VMs /Volumes/WINSTALL
$ rm -rf support
$ mkdir support
$ echo "Copying files to make support.iso. This may take a while."
Copying files to make support.iso. This may take a while.
$ cp -RXn /Volumes/WINSTALL/AutoUnattend.xml support/MyAutoUnattend.xml
$ echo "Making support.iso"
Making support.iso
$ hdiutil makehybrid -udf -ov -o support.iso support
Creating hybrid image...
..............

$ rm -r support
$ popd
/Volumes/WINSTALL

***************
*** SUCCESS ***
***************
```

Output from the `./mywindows create -i Windows7 -m 512 GSP1RMCPRXFRER_EN_DVD.ISO` command.

```
mywindows create: Using implicit device: BOOTCAMP
$ # Enter the commands below to create the virtual machine.
$ echo "Making sure the BOOTCAMP device is unmounted."
Making sure the BOOTCAMP device is unmounted.
$ diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | grep -Eq "^ *Mounted: *No$" || diskutil unmount "BOOTCAMP"
Volume BOOTCAMP on disk0s3 unmounted
$ vboxmanage createvm --name MyWindows --ostype "Windows7" --register
Virtual machine 'MyWindows' is created and registered.
UUID: 2ced668d-b5e9-4e51-8c04-e85878455907
Settings file: '/Users/dma/VirtualBox VMs/MyWindows/MyWindows.vbox'
$ echo "Configuring virtual machine hardware."
Configuring virtual machine hardware.
$ vboxmanage modifyvm MyWindows --memory "512" --cpus "1" --vram "32" --mouse usbtablet --ioapic on --pae on
$ echo "Adding virtual DVDs to the virtual machine."
Adding virtual DVDs to the virtual machine.
$ VBoxManage storagectl MyWindows --name IDE --add ide --controller PIIX4       
$ # Primary Master
$ VBoxManage storageattach MyWindows --storagectl IDE --port 0 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium "GSP1RMCPRXFRER_EN_DVD.ISO"
$ # Secondary Master
$ VBoxManage storageattach MyWindows --storagectl IDE --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium "$HOME/VirtualBox VMs/support.iso"
$ echo "Added partition containing the BOOTCAMP device to the virtual machine."
Added partition containing the BOOTCAMP device to the virtual machine.
$ vboxmanage storagectl MyWindows --name SATA --add sata --controller IntelAhci --portcount 1 --hostiocache on
$ pushd "$HOME/VirtualBox VMs/MyWindows"
~/VirtualBox VMs/MyWindows /Volumes/WINSTALL
$ sudo vboxmanage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename bootcamp.vmdk -rawdisk "/dev/disk0" -partitions "3"
RAW host disk access VMDK file bootcamp.vmdk created successfully.
$ sudo chown "$USER" bootcamp*.vmdk
$ [[ $(stat -f '%Lp' "/dev/disk0s3") == 666 ]] || sudo chmod 666 "/dev/disk0s3"
$ vboxmanage closemedium disk bootcamp.vmdk
$ vboxmanage storageattach MyWindows --storagectl SATA --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium bootcamp.vmdk
$ popd
/Volumes/WINSTALL

***************
*** SUCCESS ***
***************
```

Output from the `./mywindows start` command.

```
mywindows start: Using implicit device: BOOTCAMP
$ # Enter the commands below to start the virtual machine.
$ echo "Making sure the BOOTCAMP device is unmounted."
Making sure the BOOTCAMP device is unmounted.
$ diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | grep -Eq "^ *Mounted: *No$" || diskutil unmount "BOOTCAMP"
$ [[ $(stat -f '%Lp' "/dev/disk0s3") == 666 ]] || sudo chmod 666 "/dev/disk0s3"
$ VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/SuppressMessages remindAboutAutoCapture,remindAboutMouseIntegration
$ echo "Starting virtual machine."
Starting virtual machine.
$ vboxmanage startvm MyWindows
Waiting for VM "MyWindows" to power on...
VM "MyWindows" has been successfully started.

***************
*** SUCCESS ***
***************
```

Output from the `./mywindows update` command.

```
mywindows update: Using implicit device: BOOTCAMP
$ # Enter the command below to update the physical MBR boot code.
$ sudo fdisk -uyf ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/MyWindows/bootcamp-pt.vmdk /dev/disk0
$ # Enter the commands below to make sure the device is mounted.
$ echo "Making sure the BOOTCAMP device is mounted."
Making sure the BOOTCAMP device is mounted.
$ diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | grep -Eq "^ *Mounted: *Yes$" || diskutil mount "BOOTCAMP"
Volume BOOTCAMP on BOOTCAMP mounted

***************
*** SUCCESS ***
***************
```

Output from the `/Volumes/WINSTALL/mywindows remove` command.

```
mywindows remove: Using implicit device: BOOTCAMP
$ # Enter the command below to remove the "~/VirtualBox VMs/support.iso" file.
$ rm -f ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/support.iso
$ # Enter the commands below to remove the virtual machine.
$ ! VBoxManage list vms | grep '"MyWindows"' || VBoxManage unregistervm MyWindows
"MyWindows" {2ced668d-b5e9-4e51-8c04-e85878455907}
$ mkdir -p ~/VirtualBox\ VMs 
$ pushd ~/VirtualBox\ VMs
~/VirtualBox VMs ~
$ rm -rf MyWindows
$ popd
~
$ [[ $(stat -f '%Lp' "/dev/disk0s3") == 640 ]] || sudo chmod 640 "/dev/disk0s3"
$ echo "Making sure the BOOTCAMP device is mounted."
Making sure the BOOTCAMP device is mounted.
$ diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | grep -Eq "^ *Mounted: *Yes$" || diskutil mount "BOOTCAMP"

***************
*** SUCCESS ***
***************
```

### Other References

- [Install Windows 7 on a (17-inch, Late 2011) MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440907/install-windows-7-on-a-17-inch-late-2011-macbook-pro)
- [How to Update Windows 7 All at Once with Microsoft’s Convenience Rollup](https://www.howtogeek.com/255435/how-to-update-windows-7-all-at-once-with-microsofts-convenience-rollup/)
- [Download Windows 7 Service Pack 2 (64 bit-32 bit)](https://geekermag.com/download-windows-7-service-pack-2/)
- [Windows 7 KB4534310 (final update) released, download offline installers](https://www.windowslatest.com/2020/01/15/windows-7-kb4534310/)
- [Drivers not working on Windows 10 installed (CLI process) on external SSD running on MacBook Air 2018](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384355/drivers-not-working-on-windows-10-installed-cli-process-on-external-ssd-runnin)
- [Dual Boot Win 7 on MBR with Win 10 on GPT](https://superuser.com/questions/1518366/dual-boot-win-7-on-mbr-with-win-10-on-gpt)
- [How can I tell if a KB or newer has been installed for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/750543/how-can-i-tell-if-a-kb-or-newer-has-been-installed-for-windows)

Answer (score -1):

User [TAbdiukov](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/369389/tabdiukov) (which is also the OP) made the following chat and comment posts. (As of March 5, 2024, most of TAbdiukov's comments had been removed.) I understand that TAbdiukov's original [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740) was based on work done 10+ years ago (at the age of 14) using a 2010 Mac mini that TAbdiukov is no longer in possession of. However, TAbdiukov has now acquired use of a 2010 Mac mini.

[image]

[image]

[image]

User [TAbdiukov](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/369389/tabdiukov) also posted the following comment.

[image: comment]

This answer is in response to this comment.

Afterwards, further changes were made to both TAbdiukov's [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno) and [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740). Below is my list of other changes or improvements to TAbdiukov's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740).

- The WinPE used in TAbdiukov's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740) to create the images was based on Windows XP. Based on the posted images, I assume this WinPE contained WinNTSetup 2.1. TAbdiukov has no explanation how to create such a WinPE or where such legacy software can be downloaded. Instead, TAbdiukov does list [Sergei Strelec's WinPE](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/sergei_strelecs_winpe.html) as a possible substitution. I think users would have more confidence in the answer if the legacy images could be replaced with current ones.
- This answer will now outline the steps needed to **run WinNTSetup 4.2.5 for a 32‑bit Windows 7 SP1 install** to a physical partition in a virtual machine using only 512 MB of memory, instead of the 1 GB required by [Sergei Strelec's WinPE](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/sergei_strelecs_winpe.html). The WinPE will be the one included in the 32‑bit Microsoft Windows 7 installer ISO file. When the Windows 7 installer boots, a ram disk is created and the `\sources\install.wim` image file is applied to the ram disk. This creates a volume name `Boot`, which is assigned the drive letter X:. This is the WinPE, which is a lot more bare bones than most offered by third parties. The same is true for Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and 11.

  Since I do not have the 32‑bit Windows 7 installation ISO file used by TAbdiukov, I substituted the file named `GSP1RMCPRXFRER_EN_DVD.ISO` from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/win-7-pro-32-64-iso). The procedure for obtaining the WinNTSetup 4.2.5 folder is documented [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/468756/tpm-2-0-on-a-macbook-pro-with-windows/468757#468757). In this answer, this folder is assumed to be named `WinNTSetup_v425`. To expose this file to the virtual machine, an ISO file was created from this folder. The command for creating a `WinNTSetup_v425.iso` ISO file from the `WinNTSetup_v425` folder is given below. This command was tested to work when using Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

  ```
  hdiutil makehybrid -udf -ov -o WinNTSetup_v425.iso WinNTSetup_v425
  ```

  The next step is to create a 32‑bit Windows 7 guest machine with 512 MB of memory and the following drive configuration on a Snow Leopard 10.6.8 host. Since I do not have Parallels 5, I substituted VirtualBox 4.3.40.

  | Controler | Port:Device | Partition or ISO File | Type | Drive Letter |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | SATA | 0:0 | `/dev/disk0s3` | HDD | C: |
  | IDE Primary Slave | 0:1 | `GSP1RMCPRXFRER_EN_DVD.ISO` | DVD | D: |
  | IDE Secondary Master | 1:0 | `WinNTSetup_v425.iso` | DVD | E: |

  When first booting this virtual machine, one arrives at the display shown below.

  [image: first screen]

  Below is after pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open a Command Prompt window.

  [image: command prompt window]

  Below is after entering the `e:\WinNTSetup_x86` command. Since all files required from the Windows 10 ADK are already on drive E:, one is not prompted to download the files.

  [image: WinNTSetup]

  See [here](https://imgur.com/a/ZTFz0Gs) for a visual comparison of this virtual machine and the one in TAbdiukov's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740). The image below shows WinNTSetup configured to install Windows 7 Ultimate.

  [image: Configured for Windows 7 Ultimate]

  The image below shows WinNTSetup installing Windows 7.

  [image: Installing Windows 7]

  The image below shows WinNTSetup having completed. The user should select the "OK' button, then assumably proceed as instructed in TAbdiukov's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740).

  [image: Afterwards]
- This answer will now outline the steps needed to **run WinNTSetup 5.3.4 for a 64‑bit Windows 11 23H2v2 install** to a physical partition in a virtual machine using 1024 MB of memory. The WinPE will be the one included in the 64‑bit Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 installer ISO file named `English_Windows_7_Professional_SP1_W64_X17-59186.iso`, which was downloaded from a now defunct Microsoft website.

  > Note: Windows 11 requires at least 4 GB of memory. The 2010 Mac mini standard memory is 2 GB, but can be increased to a maximum of 16 GB. I do  not know how much memory is installed in TAbdiukov's Mac.

  The procedure for obtaining the WinNTSetup 5.3.4 folder is documented [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/468756/tpm-2-0-on-a-macbook-pro-with-windows/468757#468757). In this answer, this folder is assumed to be named `WinNTSetup_v534`. To expose this file to the virtual machine, an ISO file named `WinNTSetup_v534.iso` was created from this folder.
  The next step is to create a 64‑bit Windows 7 guest machine with 1024 MB of memory and the following drive configuration on a Snow Leopard 10.6.8 host. Since I do not have Parallels 5, I substituted VirtualBox 4.3.40. The `Win11_23H2_English_x64v2.iso` file was downloaded from this Micrsoft [Download Windows 11](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) website.

  | Controler | Port:Device | Partition or ISO File | Type | Drive Letter |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | SATA | 0:0 | `/dev/disk0s3` | HDD | C: |
  | IDE Primary Slave | 0:1 | `English_Windows_7_Professional_SP1_W64_X17-59186.iso` | DVD | D: |
  | IDE Secondary Master | 1:0 | `WinNTSetup_v534.iso` | DVD | E: |
  | IDE Secondary Slave | 1:1 | `Win11_23H2_English_x64v2.iso` | DVD | F: |

  When first booting this virtual machine, one arrives at the display shown below.

  [image: first screen]

  Below is after pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open a Command Prompt window.

  [image: command prompt window]

  Below is after entering the `e:\WinNTSetup_x86` command. Since all files required from the Windows 10 ADK are already on drive E:, one is not prompted to download the files.

  [image: WinNTSetup]

  See [here](https://imgur.com/a/ZTFz0Gs) for a visual comparison of this virtual machine and the one in TAbdiukov's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740). The image below shows WinNTSetup configured to install Windows 11 Pro. Note that the `v22H2` shown in wrong. The version actual being installed is `v23H2`.

  [image: Configured for Windows 11 Pro]

  The image below shows WinNTSetup installing Windows 11.

  [image: Installing Windows 11]

  The image below shows WinNTSetup having completed. The user should select the "OK' button, then assumably proceed as instructed in TAbdiukov's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740).

  [image: Afterwards]

  The images below are from after completing the installation. One can see the version is `23H2`.

  [image: Desktop]

  [image: System > About]
- There is no need for a "Mac OS X Recovery & Installation disk image". TAbdiukov's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740) answer needs this file to create a bootable Mac OS X USB flash drive. This flash drive then needed in order to use the `dd` command. This command requires all volumes of `disk0` to be unmounted in order to gain write access to the MBR. My [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/467849#467849) uses the `fdisk` command instead. This command only requires shared access to `disk0` in order to do write operations. Shared access means volumes on `disk0` can remain mounted while `fdisk` writes to the MBR. This is true even for newer versions of OS X/macOS where SIP is employed. Although with SIP, one would have to either disable SIP or execute the `fdisk` command while booted to the Recovery partition on `disk0`.
- TAbdiukov's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740) mentions using only two hotfixes (KB4474419 and KB3138612) to get Windows Update to work. In testing using the two hotfixes, I found I could not get all available updates to install without having to eventually manually apply some of 5 hotfixes given in [my other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/467849#467849).
- I think TAbdiukov's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466739/how-to-install-windows-7-and-beyond-onto-a-mid-2010-mac-mini-with-mac-os-x-sno/466740#466740) answer could be improved by at least mentioning Parallels up to version 9 is compatible with Snow Leopard. The [Parallels Desktop 9 for Mac User's Guide](https://download.parallels.com/desktop/v9/ga/docs/en_US/Parallels%20Desktop%20User%27s%20Guide.pdf?_gl=1%2Agkxe8e%2A_gcl_au%2ANzk5ODE2MTk4LjE3MDEzMzc0ODQ.%2A_ga%2AMjA2MDIwNjQ2Ny4xNzAxMzM3NDg0%2A_ga_CEVYC7924W%2AMTcwNDI0NDI3NS45LjEuMTcwNDI0NTA4NC4zMC4wLjA.&_ga=2.260079182.219085396.1704244276-2060206467.1701337484) shows supported hosts on page 12 and support guests starting on page 130. Snow Leopard 10.6.8 is listed as a host. Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 are on the list as guests, but Windows 10 and 11 are not.

### My Test Environment

I do not have a 2010 Mac mini. I do not have a version of Parallels older enough to be used for testing. I substituted the following.

- A 2007 iMac with 4 GB of memory. Snow Leopard (64‑bit) 10.6.8 was the host when VirtualBox 4.3.40 was used. The VirtualBox guests were Windows 7 through 11 installers or PEs.
- A 2013 iMac with 16 GB of memory. Catalina 10.15.7 was the host when Fusion Player 12.1.2 was used. The Fusion Player guests were Lion 10.7.5 and Windows 7 through 11. Lion was used, because I did not have a Snow Leopard that would run in Fusion Player. Lion was the host when VirtualBox 4.3.40 was used. The VirtualBox guests were Windows 7 through 11 installers or PEs. This nested use of virtual machines allowed me to virtualize both the host and guest.

### Other References

- [TPM 2.0 on a MacBook Pro with Windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/468756/tpm-2-0-on-a-macbook-pro-with-windows)
- [Download links for legacy Parallels Desktop versions](https://kb.parallels.com/5802)
- [Sergei Strelec](https://sergeistrelec.name/)
- [Download links for legacy Parallels Desktop versions](https://kb.parallels.com/5802)